# Reorder objects based on provided enumerable order

Tags: c#, linq

This code feels like it goes through too many conversions to accomplish my goal:

> based on an IEnumerable of ids get those objects from a data store and
>   set their `DisplayOrder` property to the position of the associated
>   id.

Is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing?

```
public void ReorderElements(IEnumerable<int> elementSks)
{
    var elementsToReorder = GetSession().QueryOver<DocumentElement>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(de => de.DocumentElementSk).IsIn(elementSks.ToArray()).List();

    var elementOrder = elementSks.Select((sk, i) => new { Sk = sk, Order = i })
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Sk, p => p.Order);

    elementsToReorder.ToList()
        .ForEach(e => e.DisplayOrder = elementOrder[e.DocumentElementSk]);

    this.Save(elementsToReorder);
}
```

Comment: Are the elementSks in any particular order when the enter the method?

Comment: @sgriffinusa The ids are posted in order from a web page and then sent to this repository method.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific, what I want to know is if they are sorted.

Comment: @sgriffinusa yes the ids are in the order I want them in. The elements retrieved from the data store are ordered by their primary key. So I have to update them based on the position of the ids in `elementSks`.

Answer (score 2):

If the list on input is going to be short, or if performance doesn't matter to you, you can simplify the code by using `IndexOf()` instead of the dictionary:

```
public void ReorderElements(IEnumerable<int> elementSks)
{
    var elementsToReorder = GetSession().QueryOver<DocumentElement>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(de => de.DocumentElementSk).IsIn(elementSks.ToArray()).List();

    var elementOrder = elementSks.ToList();

    foreach(var element in elementsToReorder)
         element.DisplayOrder = elementOrder.IndexOf(element.DocumentElementSk);

    this.Save(elementsToReorder);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. I wrote this without testing or even compiling.

```
public void ReorderElements(IEnumerable<int> elementSks)
{
    var skToElementsToReorder = GetSession().QueryOver<DocumentElement>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(de => de.DocumentElementSk).IsIn(elementSks.ToArray())
        .ToDictionary(el => el.DocumentElementSk, el => el);

    int index = 0;
    foreach(int sk in elementSks)
    {
        // Assumes that the key exists - the .IsIn restriction right before helps
        skToElementsToReorder[sk].DisplayOrder = index++;
    }

    this.Save(elementsToReorder);
}
```

Somehow I think that this can help: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b (as long as you can zip elementSks together with an index. Let me try a simpler version:

```
public class /* or struct ? */Element 
{
    public string name;
    public in sk;
    public int index;
}

// I am not fluent in LINQ, but Linq.Zip might help to generate these?
public class SkTuple
{
    int sk;
    int index;
}

// Now you have an `IEnumerable` of each somehow, and you want to do an update at the same time as you do a join ... like this?
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709560/linq-in-line-property-update-during-join

This kind of got me thinking that maybe SQL is king after all - perhaps you want to just save this list of ids into a temp table where table id will be the index, and then call a stored procedure which will use a join and an update like [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201023061551/http://geekswithblogs.net/faizanahmad/archive/2009/01/05/join-in-sql-update--statement.aspx).

Comment: The linq to retrieve `elementsToReorder` is NHibernate's new QueryOver syntax. It's just a rehashing of their ICriteria expression syntax. It boils down to SQL and doesn't have that much affect on performance. Everything after the object retrieval is what I'm most worried about.